# Compiling a Linux driver for a TV card stack

Tags: drivers, raspberry-pi, cross-compilation, dvb

I've been trying to get my Raspberry Pi to work with one of two TV Cards that I have available on me. Unfortunately I live in Hong Kong where due to the digital broadcast standard, leaves me with few choices of devices. Neither of which seem to want to play ball.

For obvious reasons, both are USB. I have "determined" that one uses a RTL2836U chipset. Whilst the other is using a LME 2510C with a Maxim 2165E tuner and 8G75-A1 demoduator.

I had been focusing my efforts to efforts on the RTL2836U and I just compiled some drivers (with the VID/PID added) and Linux seemed to load the modules, but then unloaded it due to an error.

dmesg

```
    dvb_hdhomerun: disagrees about version of symbol dvb_dmxdev_init
    dvb_hdhomerun: Unknown symbol dvb_dmxdev_init (err -22)
    dvb_hdhomerun: disagrees about version of symbol dvb_register_adapter
    dvb_hdhomerun: Unknown symbol dvb_register_adapter (err -22)
    dvb_hdhomerun: disagrees about version of symbol dvb_dmxdev_release
    dvb_hdhomerun: Unknown symbol dvb_dmxdev_release (err -22)
    dvb_hdhomerun: disagrees about version of symbol dvb_frontend_detach
    dvb_hdhomerun: Unknown symbol dvb_frontend_detach (err -22)
    dvb_hdhomerun: disagrees about version of symbol dvb_unregister_frontend
    dvb_hdhomerun: Unknown symbol dvb_unregister_frontend (err -22)
    dvb_hdhomerun: disagrees about version of symbol dvb_register_frontend
    dvb_hdhomerun: Unknown symbol dvb_register_frontend (err -22)
    dvb_hdhomerun: disagrees about version of symbol dvb_unregister_adapter
    dvb_hdhomerun: Unknown symbol dvb_unregister_adapter (err -22)
    bcm2708 watchdog, heartbeat=10 sec (nowayout=0)
```

tail -f /var/log/kern.log

```
Mar  1 03:14:06 raspbmc kernel: dvb_hdhomerun: Unknown symbol dvb_dmxdev_release (err -22)
Mar  1 03:14:06 raspbmc kernel: dvb_hdhomerun: disagrees about version of symbol dvb_frontend_detach
Mar  1 03:14:06 raspbmc kernel: dvb_hdhomerun: Unknown symbol dvb_frontend_detach (err -22)
Mar  1 03:14:06 raspbmc kernel: dvb_hdhomerun: disagrees about version of symbol dvb_unregister_frontend
Mar  1 03:14:06 raspbmc kernel: dvb_hdhomerun: Unknown symbol dvb_unregister_frontend (err -22)
Mar  1 03:14:06 raspbmc kernel: dvb_hdhomerun: disagrees about version of symbol dvb_register_frontend
Mar  1 03:14:06 raspbmc kernel: dvb_hdhomerun: Unknown symbol dvb_register_frontend (err -22)
Mar  1 03:14:06 raspbmc kernel: dvb_hdhomerun: disagrees about version of symbol dvb_unregister_adapter
Mar  1 03:14:06 raspbmc kernel: dvb_hdhomerun: Unknown symbol dvb_unregister_adapter (err -22)
Mar  1 03:14:18 raspbmc kernel: bcm2708 watchdog, heartbeat=10 sec (nowayout=0)
```

Then on insert of the dongle

```
Mar  1 03:21:07 raspbmc kernel: usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
Mar  1 03:21:07 raspbmc kernel: usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=1f4d,idProduct=689b
Mar  1 03:21:07 raspbmc kernel: usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Mar  1 03:21:07 raspbmc kernel: usb 1-1.3: Product: USB Device
Mar  1 03:21:07 raspbmc kernel: usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: realtek
Mar  1 03:21:07 raspbmc kernel: usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 00000005
Mar  1 03:21:07 raspbmc kernel: WARNING: You are using an experimental version of the media stack.
Mar  1 03:21:07 raspbmc kernel:         As the driver is backported to an olderkernel, it doesn't offer
Mar  1 03:21:07 raspbmc kernel:         enough quality for its usage in production.
Mar  1 03:21:07 raspbmc kernel:         Use it with care.
Mar  1 03:21:07 raspbmc kernel: Latest git patches (needed if you report a bug to linux-media@vger.kernel.org):
Mar  1 03:21:07 raspbmc kernel:         ed72d37a33fdf43dc47787fe220532cdec9da528 [media] media: Add 0x3009 USB PID to ttusb2 driver (fixed diff)
Mar  1 03:21:07 raspbmc kernel:         b9e2afff1e6b36d05a0e12b6114eb0aaf8949c09 [media] rtl28xxu: Add USB IDs for Compro VideoMate U620F
Mar  1 03:21:07 raspbmc kernel:         676fa7d4c9fd141a31cba2870e592a597c0bb07f [media] em28xx: add usb id for terratec h5 rev. 3
Mar  1 03:21:07 raspbmc kernel: usb 1-1.3: dvb_usb_v2: found a 'MYGICA D690U' in warm state
Mar  1 03:21:07 raspbmc kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver dvb_usb_rtl28xxu
Mar  1 03:21:10 raspbmc kernel: usb 1-1.3: dvb_usb_v2: 'MYGICA D690U' error while loading driver (-110)
Mar  1 03:21:10 raspbmc kernel: usb 1-1.3: dvb_usb_v2: 'MYGICA D690U' successfully deinitialized and disconnected
```

Aptitude is showing me these modules

```
v   linux-headers
p   linux-headers-2.6-mx5
p   linux-headers-2.6-omap
p   linux-headers-3.2.0-4-all
p   linux-headers-3.2.0-4-all-armhf
p   linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common
p   linux-headers-3.2.0-4-rpi
i   linux-headers-generic
p   linux-headers-mx5
p   linux-headers-omap
p   linux-headers-vexpress
v   linux-kernel-headers
```

Comment: The kernel version would also help. And the distribution.

Comment: @schaiba Rasbian 3.6.11

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, your error stems from the version incompatibility between the running kernel and the kernel version you're building the modules against. Check `uname -r` against your tree.

Comment: As apt-get doesn't seem to have a kernel headers package for 3.6.11 I had to download the kernel source and rebuild them. Although I read somewhere I only need to 'make modules' rather than a full make. If I need to full on replace the kernel I'd likely need to cross compile...The pi is pretty darn slow. What do you suggest?

Comment: If you search for kernel headers with aptitude, what results do you get?

Comment: So you have kernel 3.6.x, but as Raspbian is Wheezy-based, it has 3.2.x . This creates the question: how did you get the 3.6.x kernel and what do you have in /etc/apt/sources.list?

Comment: The kernel was built into the Raspbmc image I started with (a Raspbian with XBMC slipped in), I downloaded the sources from https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux, the master 'branch' looks to be 3.6.11.

Comment: I just found this thread on another forum. Will try it out this weekend. http://forum.stmlabs.com/showthread.php?tid=6780 But thanks for the help so far. I will report my progress either way.

Comment: Hey Aron. I found this question you made and I'm having exactly the same issue - albeit not for a tv card stack. How did you end up solving it? I also downloaded the headers of a different kernel version as they weren't on the pi.